# R: How to seperate values and subtract from next row in a table?

Tags: r, function, subtraction

Right now, I have a table as so:

```
Time  Jack    Kate
1    105~100   88~99
2    100~107   90~91
3    101~99    98~91
(etc)
```

I want to make it so that the "~" gets separated and I can get the first values of Jack and Kate in the Current row, and subtract it from the difference of the second value of Jack and Kate. So it will first be (105-88)-(107-91), and then (100-90)-(99-91), etc.

I have:
`splt <- strsplit(x, slit="~', fixed=TRUE)`

I tried using tapply, but I don't know how to refer to each row as the function progresses. Apologize for my lack of knowledge, but I'm not sure how to go about this or if tapply is the right function here.

Cheers

Comment: can you use `dput` on your data set and post the result here?

Answer (score 1):

You had a good start with `strsplit`. After that, you can use the fact that the indexing operator "[" is a function that you can apply to the lists to get all of the individual numbers from your original strings.

```
## Your sample data
df = read.table(text="Time Jack Kate 
1 105~100 88~99 
2 100~107 90~91 
3 101~99 98~91",
header=TRUE, 
stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Jack1 = as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(df$Jack, "~"), "[", 1))
Jack2 = as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(df$Jack, "~"), "[", 2))
Kate1 = as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(df$Kate, "~"), "[", 1))
Kate2 = as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(df$Kate, "~"), "[", 2))
Jack1
[1] 105 100 101
```

Now you can just compute the differences that you wanted.

```
(Jack1 - Kate1)[-length(Jack1)] - (Jack2 - Kate2)[-1]
[1] 1 2
```